# Intercept the Model Validation in asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to figure out which method sets the `ModelState` in an asp.net WebApi controller. I need to be able to inspect the `ModelState.IsValid` as the `ModelState` property is set. I've tried overriding a bunch of methods, to no avail.

Comment: Its set by the `DefaultModelBinder` when your method is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the model validation support from `validationAttribute` and many can be found in
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)

if you want to customize your own model validation, you can create [custom validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation)